# Jenkins Pipeline not showing how many changes were pulled in since last build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like Jenkins to show me the changes to code since the last build took place, however at the moment it is only showing me changes to my pipeline groovy script (as it takes this from SVN).

I have tried adding a checkout step (generated by the snippet generator) and I can see the code being checked out, however when I look next to the build number, it still says 'No Changes'.

```
checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[credentialsId: 'xxx', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: '.', remote: 'http://xxxxxxxxx:8080/$JOB_NAME/trunk']], workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']])
```

[image: Jenkins-NoChanges]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Stupid question, but are there any changes?

Comment: Yes, there were changes to several files, however Jenkins only appears to highlight when changes were made to my jenkins pipeline groovy file

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins is now showing the changes since I added -

```
checkout changelog: true,
```

Not sure why I had to set this explicitly since the default is true, but it works, so not complaining :-)